# VS-code terminal not recognising conda environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am using VSCode on MacOS and the VSCode terminal is not recognising conda environment. Instead it directing to directing to the original python environment that came along with MacOS (`/usr/bin/python`).

I have tried a few suggestion from other post such as,

- `conda init` followed by closing and re-opening terminal
- opening code from terminal (MacOS terminal) with the environment already activated

  - `conda activate ml3.10` on MacOS terminal followed by `code .`
- uninstalling vscode `rm -rf ~./vscode*` and `rm -r /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

but nothing has worked so far. Any ideas whats the problem

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is due to the vscode settings. Maybe you can try following steps:

1.Find code->preference->setting->Features->Terminal->Integrad>Env:Osx in vscode and choose edit in settings.json;

2.Add code below

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {  
          "PATH": ""   
 }
```

to the red frame.[image]